# How do I get rid of unused variable warning on double arrow function?

Tags: node.js, variables, arrow-functions

I am getting an unused variable (for 'dispatch') for both getPlanA and getPlanB functions...

How do I (or can I) pass 'dispatch' to the 'getPlan' function to get rid of the unused var warning?

```
export const getPlanA = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  return getPlan(userId, true);
};

export const getPlanB = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  return getPlan(userId, false);
};

const getPlan = (id, isPlanA) => (dispatch) => {
   
  if(isPlanA){
   dispatch(setPlanALoading());
  } else {
   dispatch(setPlanBLoading());
  }

}
```

NOTE: this code comes from a REACT project, these are the action functions that will call an API...

Comment: Can you explain in plain English this code does? Why have you wrapped an arrow function within another arrow function? Is that really necessary?

Comment: Are you talking about [this eslint warning](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#args)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getPlanA` and `getPlanB` don't use the `dispatch` parameter, because they're calling `getPlan` incorrectly.

`getPlan` is a function that creates a function. If you want to "bake in" the plan A / B aspect in `getPlanA`/`getPlanB`, they should return the function `getPlan` returns, not create their own function, like this:

```
export const getPlanA = (id) => {
    return getPlan(id, true);
};

export const getPlanB = (id) => {
    return getPlan(id, false);
};

const getPlan = (id, isPlanA) => (dispatch) => {
    if (isPlanA) {
        dispatch(setPlanALoading());
    } else {
        dispatch(setPlanBLoading());
    }
};
```

(Note that I also changed the `userId` parameter to `id` to match what you used when calling `getPlan`.)

---

> How do I (or can I) pass 'dispatch' to the 'getPlan' function...

Just for clarity: You don't, in `getPlanA`/`getPlanB`. `getPlan` isn't the function that expects to receive `dispatch`, it's the function `getPlan` *returns* that expects to receive dispatch. So `getPlanA`/`getPlanB` just return that function to the caller, and it's the caller's responsibility to call it (when/if appropriate), just like it is with `getPlan`.